# On close Excel updated file send email or skype message using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, skype

I need Excel VBA code in such way that whenever I close and updated Excel file (data must have been updated in the file), send a Skype Message or Email to other people stating that file was updated.

I'm looking for a VBA code where I can achieve this.

Important: The code is for Skype or Mozilla Thunderbird.

Comment: Have you tried to use an existing alternative? Like Google docs for instance, you can turn on notifications as stated [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/91588?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-send-outlook-email-notification-specific-excel-worksheet-updated/) is a good article with VBA code on how to send an email when a Specific Excel Worksheet Is Updated.

Here is the code being used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nConfirmation As Integer
    Dim objNewWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objNewWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim objOutlookApp As Object
    Dim objMail As Object

    nConfirmation = MsgBox("Do you want to send an email notification about the sheet updating now?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Mail Sheet Updates")

    If nConfirmation = vbYes Then
       ActiveWorkbook.Save

       On Error Resume Next
       Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
       Set objMail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

       'Change the email details as per your needs
       With objMail
           .To = "test@datanumen.com"
           .Subject = "Email Notifying Sheet Updates"
           .Body = "Hi," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "The worksheet " & Chr(34) & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & Chr(34) & " in this Excel workbook attachment is updated."
           'Attach this workbook
           .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
           .Send
      End With
    End If
End Sub
```

It can be useful as a starting point.

Comment: Is there anything for skype or email client Thunderbird? because the below VBA code is for outlook it seems.

Comment: That could be a good homework to you to find ;) keyword: SMTP